# What are the topological groups the points of which are separated by their finite-dimensional representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

It is known that the continuous finite-dimensional irreducible unitary representations separate the points of Hausdorff compact topological groups (this is, in part, the Peter-Weyl theorem). These, though, are not the only such groups - $\mathbb R^n$ is so, too. My question, therefore, is:

> is it possible to characterize the topological groups the points of which can be separated by their continuous finite-dimensional representations?